# How to fix webpage number of spaces formatting error?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align the text on t my webpage in this manner:

Issue-Date:       03/12/2019 
Due Date:           04/02/2019 
Net:                         12 
P.O #:                   1/3-147

But I am getting it like this:

Issue-Date: 03/12/2019 
Due Date: 04/02/2019 
Net: 12
P.O #: 1/3-147

How do I implement the first format without hardcoding the number of spaces without hardcoding the number of spaces?

Comment: Have you tried something? For example you can use flexbox. If you read the documentation about bootstrap 4 you can find a lot of helper for flexbox class. I'll suggest to start from reading that docs, try to code a solution , and if you get stuck ask here showing your attemps

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some HTML tags like div, span and the apply your CSS on them, something like this would works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        Issue-Date:
    </div>
    <div>
        03/12/2019
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens if an item is wider than 100px?

Comment: you can change it by percent too like this 10%. smaller or greater value will cause on width of panel, by change it you can fix the view based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Given a meaningful markup, like a description list, you could use `display: grid` to achieve that layout

Doing so you don't need to set a `width` (or a `min-width`) to the item on the left and the column will auto-adapt itself

```css
dl {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "c1 c2";
   grid-auto-columns: min-content;
}

dt,dd { margin: 0; }

dt { grid-area: "c1"; white-space: nowrap; }
dd { grid-area: "c2"; padding-left: 10px; }
```

```html
<dl>
   <dt>Issue-Date</dt>    
   <dd>03/12/2019</dd>
   
   <dt>Due Date</dt>      
   <dd>04/02/2019</dd>
   
   <dt>Net:</dt>               
   <dd>12</dd>
   
   <dt>A really long item</dt>          
   <dd>1/3-147</dd>

   <dt>P.O #</dt>          
   <dd>1/3-147</dd>
</dl>
```